# awk through text file with different delimiter count into array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have a text file that has 8000 lines, here is an example

> 00122;IL;Chicago;Router;;1496009459
>
> 00133;IL;Chicago;Router;0;6.651;1496009460
>
> 00166;IL;Chicago;Router;0;5.798;1496009460
>
> 00177;IL;Chicago;Router;0;5.365;1496009460
>
> 00188;IL;Chicago;Router;0;22.347;1496009460

As you can see the file has different count of delimiter, I need to insert all  columns separated by ';' to an array no matter when the the delimiter occurs
So the first line would have 6 fields and the second line would have 7.

When I tried do it through the below command
Number=( $(awk '{print $1}' $FileName.txt) ) with different array name and field for each columns, I am getting strange behavior which not all fields are printed for some lines when I echo them all in one line

Performance is very important (need to do it in a matter of seconds )and I found using awk is the fastest approach so far, unless someone has better approach.
An ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: what do mean with *to insert to an array*? what is the expected output?

Comment: Are you looking to get every field of every line into the same array? Are you planning on using and then clearing the array between line reads? Or do you want a different array for each line? If you put all fields of every line into the same array at the same time, your data is going to get very disorganized. Especially since your lines don't always have matching field amounts.

Comment: this smells like an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Guest yes i want every field to be in the same array, even if the data will be distorted. so based on the first two lines of my text file F5 will have empty value from the first line and 0 from the second line and F6 will have 1496009459 from the first line and  6.651 from the second line.
Sorry for not being clear at the beginning. 
For me the empty value will be indication that I should escape the line through my loop process as this line will have incorrect data. I hope I explained it well now

Comment: If i understand correctly, your issue will be that any empty fields, such as field 5 in the first line, will be eaten when you output that to your array in bash.  You would be better served using a while loop and populating the array.

Answer (score 0):

To dump the entire text file into an array, I would use the following. In this example, we use the two arrays `${finalarray[]}` and `${subarray[]}` (though the latter is unset at the end) and the variable `$line`. We assume the file name is `file.txt`.

```
#!/bin/bash
finalarray=()
while read line; do #For each cycle, the variable $line is the next line of the file
    if [[ -z $line ]]; then continue; done #If the line is empty, skip this cycle
    IFS=";" read -r -a subarray <<< "$line" #Split $line into ${subarray[]} using : as delim
    finalarray+=( "$subarray[@]}" ) #Add every element from ${subarray[]} to ${finalarray[]}
    unset subarray #clears the array
done <file.txt
```

If your empty lines are, in fact, populated by spaces or other whitespace characters, the empty line catch won't work. Instead, you could use something like the following to skip any lines not containing semicolons.

```
if [[ $(echo "$line" | grep -c ";") -eq 0 ]]; then continue; fi
```

On the other hand, this would skip *all* lines without a semicolon, even if you intended some of those lines to be a single array entry.